# Android Studio new project error in main activity.kt (basic activity)

Tags: android, kotlin, new-project

everyone I'm very new to android studio, after creating a basic activity project and all building process, it throws an error in main activity(.kt). All 4 Navigation errors in imports. what should I do now
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFo8J.png) Thanks in advance and answer me in detail, so I can follow up you

````
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity  
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import com.pawanindrayan.notetoself.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> true
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}```
````

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle.kts code and post thrown error?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please also post the content of your app level build. gradle file. It seems you are missing the dependencies for androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx and androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx